# Change value with sed/awk using value that changes

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Basically i need to create multiple files containing one line and substitute that line with value which i get from loop. Maybe my little code will explain better then i am.

```
#!/bin/bash
DATE=$(date +%F -d 2014-06-01)
for echo in {1..5}
do
echo "<TAG></TAG>" > output$echo.xml
done
for i in {1..5}
    do
NEXT_DATE=$(date +%F -d "$DATE + $i month")
SET=$(date +%F -d "$NEXT_DATE + $i month")
sed -i "s|<TAG></TAG>|<TAG>$SET{1..5}</TAG>|" output{1..5}.xml
done
```

It generates me output1.xml, output2.xml ...
I just cant figure out how to add that generated date valu between tags after running that script. Desired output would be:

output1.xml contains:

```
"<TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>"
```

output2.xml contains:

```
"<TAG>2014-10-01</TAG>"
```

and so on.
Right now it substitutes it with generated date value + {1..5}, like so:

```
<TAG>2014-08-01{1..5}</TAG>
```

How can i achive that?

Comment: Why do you have `{1..5}` in the `sed` command if you didn't want that in the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for two loops or `awk`. Just put the date into the file in the first loop:

```
DATE=$(date +%F -d 2014-06-01)
for i in {1..5}
do
    NEXT_DATE=$(date +%F -d "$DATE + $i month")
    SET=$(date +%F -d "$NEXT_DATE + $i month")
    echo "<TAG>$SET</TAG>" > output$i.xml
done
```

Comment: Thank you for quick answer.
It will generate me files, but every file contains the same, like so:
   `<TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>`

What i need is:
   `<TAG>2014-08-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2014-10-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2014-12-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2015-02-01</TAG>
    <TAG>2015-04-01</TAG>`

Comment: I didn't notice that you changed variable names between the two loops. I fixed it.